# How to avoid superglobals using PHPMD

Tags: php, phpmd

I really love [phpmd](http://phpmd.org/) to ensure a minimum level of code quality in our PHP projects. Now I like to add a rule to dectect the use of superglobals. But I do not want to have the whole [controversial ruleset](http://phpmd.org/rules/controversial.html) included. I tried the following line (phpmd installed with composer):

```
vendor/bin/phpmd src/ text codesize,design,naming,unusedcode,Superglobals
```

But the output is the following:

```
Cannot find specified rule-set "Superglobals".
```

Does anyone knows how to add a single rule in phpmd?

Comment: Can you expand on "not working" a bit more? What happens when you run this?

Comment: I have edited the post and copied the output from the command.

Comment: Just guessing, have you tried lower case? All the others are.

Comment: Yes, I tried it lowercase, first thing I guessed, too. After taking a deep look into the documentation, the solution is probably by defining a ruleset.xml but I hope there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a file phpmd.rules.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="No controversial but superglobals"
         xmlns="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0 http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd">
    <description> Rulesets without controversial rules but including the check for superglobals </description> 
    <rule ref="rulesets/codesize.xml" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/design.xml" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/naming.xml" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/unusedcode.xml" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/controversial.xml/Superglobals" />
</ruleset>
```

To use these rules, you can use the following command (phpmd installed locally in your project with composer):

```
 vendor/bin/phpmd src/ text phpmd.xml
```

More details can be found on http://phpmd.org/documentation/creating-a-ruleset.html